# How to output date/time in moment without timezone shift

Tags: javascript, timestamp, momentjs

I have a timestamp from the backend and I want to display it with momentjs per console.log() without timeshifting and completly indepented from my browsers timezone. I read many posts on stackoverflow but nothing works. All of my outputs have some timezone included.

```
let timestamp = "2019-11-19T07:05:00+01:00";
console.log(moment(timestamp).toISOString(true));
console.log(moment.utc(timestamp).format());
console.log(moment.utc(timestamp).toISOString(true)); 
console.log(moment.parseZone(timestamp).format());
console.log(moment.parseZone(timestamp).local().format());
console.log(moment.parseZone(timestamp).utc().format());
console.log(moment(timestamp).utcOffset(timestamp).toISOString(true));
console.log(moment.tz(timestamp, 'Europe/Berlin').toISOString(true));
console.log(moment.tz(timestamp, 'Europe/Berlin').format());
console.log(moment.tz(timestamp, 'Europe/Berlin').unix());
console.log(moment.parseZone(timestamp).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
console.log(moment(timestamp).utcOffset("+0100").format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'));
```

expected output: 
2019-11-19T07:05:00Z
The Timezone of the timestamp is: Europe/Berlin
My Browsers timezone is switched to something different.
I don't understand why this simple problem has no easy solution. :)

Comment: Sorry was a typo. I want the same date as output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To meet the requirement you described (keeping the local time while changing the offset) you can do the following:

```js
var result = moment.parseZone("2019-11-19T07:05:00+01:00").utcOffset(0, true).format();
console.log(result); //=> "2019-11-19T07:05:00Z"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Step by step explained:

```
moment.parseZone("2019-11-19T07:05:00+01:00") // Parses the string, retaining the offset provided
      .utcOffset(0, true)  // sets the offset to zero while keeping the local time
      .format()            // formats the output, using Z to represent UTC
```

**However** - You should recognize that these are not the same moments in time.  The output timestamp is one hour earlier than the input timestamp.  This is explained [in the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) as follows (emphasis mine):

> The `utcOffset` function has an optional second parameter which
>   accepts a boolean value indicating whether to keep the existing time
>   of day.
>
> - Passing `false` (the default) will keep the same instant in Universal Time, but the local time will change.
> - Passing `true` will keep the same local time, **but at the expense of choosing a different point in Universal Time**.

Thus, it is usually the wrong choice when you already have a specific point in time, either in UTC or as an offset from UTC (like your example input value).

Instead, you should expect that converting from local time to UTC will indeed change the date and time portion of the timestamp.  You can use `.utcOffset(0, false)`, or `.utcOffset(0)`, or simply `.utc()` to do the conversion correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but it does not work in my environment.
My browsers output with console.log() is: 2019-11-19T00:05:00Z
My browser is set to timezone "America/Chicago"
Any ideas why?

Comment: The browser time zone should not affect this particular code.  Nothing here is based on local time.  I edited my response to use a runnable code snippet so you can see the exact code working.   You might want to check your code carefully, including inputs and output, and whether you are using a recent version of Moment or an old one.

Comment: Ok you are right. I had an Addon installed for Firefox to change the timezone for testing the Tool in other timezones. I think this Addon manipulates the date strings in some wired way. I removed it and changed the timezone with environment variables. Your code works fine. Thank you.